# Отличия некоторых способов вывода в php

Tags: php

Никак не могу найти, а в чем отличие STDOUT и echo? И что надо использовать, если требуется вывести данные в стандартный поток вывода? Например, как вывести переменную в стандартный поток вывода?

```
echo $i ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И то и то выводит в поток вывода, разницу можно легко показать примером:

```
ob_start();
echo 'Текст 1';
fwrite(STDOUT, 'Текст 2');
$out = ob_get_clean();
print $out;
```

Документация http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php

Простыми словами, пока активен `ob_start` то все что мы посылаем на вывод, должно перехватываться и потом записываться в `$out`, мы получается сперва получили `Текст 1` а только потом `Текст 2`, но результат будет такой:

```
Текст 2
Текст 1
```

Можно сказать что `STDOUT` прям напрямик отправит, а `echo` будет подлежать обработке, а потом отправит.